# Disks freezes but usage is 0%

Tags: windows, hard-drive, freeze

After pluging second GPU (RTX 3060) my disks started to work slow and freezes. Disk usage in task manager is 0% for each disks. I removed my first GPU (RTX 2060s) but it didn't help. I turned off my PC and checked all cables (plug out and plug in) and after power on it worked good. Then I mounted back RTX 2060s  and the problem came back. Already tried CMOS clear, BIOS update and system reinstall but it didn't helped. Any app  that uses disk freezez for couple minutes and then suddenly works for a moment. Disk usage is 0%.

My setup:

- os - Windows 10 20H2 10.0.19042 Build 19042
- mobo - MSI B450 Tomahawk MAX
- cpu - AMD Ryzen 7 1700X
- ram - G.Skill aegis 2x8GB
- gpu1 - MSI RTX2060S Gaming X
- gpu2 - MSI RTX3060 Gaming X
- ssd1 - Samsung 500GB M.2 PCIe NVMe 970 EVO
- ssd2 - Crucial MX500 500GB sata
- hdd1 - WD BLUE 2TB
- hdd2 - Toshiba 1TB

**EDIT:**

I found out that when using virtual machine there is no problems on guest.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried uninstalling drivers using DDU and reinstalling it but it didn't help so I tried solution that solved issue before - turned off pc and unplug - plug all cables. Then I got no such partition grub error. I tried updating bios and then I was able to boot into Windows and it looks the problem is gone.

Comment: What makes you think that it is the disk that is frozen?

Comment: It affects only programs that use disk. For example when I had some songs on Spotify downloaded I wasn't able to play them (it played couple seconds and then freezes for some time) while there was no problem with others. Also copying files works for couple  seconds, then freezes for couple minutes, works for couple seconds and freezes again.

Comment: Do you have issues with the 3060 in PCI_E1 even if PCI_E4 is empty? Which SATA ports are you using?

Comment: Currently I have only 2060S in my PC (same setup as before problem started) and still disks works terrible. Im  using three of SATA1-4 (SATA5 and 6 are disabled when using NVMe disk).

Comment: All disks? Or one particular drive?

Comment: The problem is with all of them and hence I think it is not caused by them.

Comment: You might try using the system internals process monitor and see what the machine is actually doing while it pauses.  It will be a PITA to get your filter small enough to see what it happening but worth it.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I look for? During freeze I observed that time stamp of consecutive event differs a lot.

Comment: If the system/programs freeze because of an HDD is often means the HDD encounters defect sectors and tries to recover them. Not sure if the system would show 0% usage in such a case. Make sure to check the SMART values of the HDD it is shows defect sectors or other failure indicators.

Comment: @Robert but I observed the problem after unpluging all disks except system disk (ssd nvme).

Comment: Since the issue only began after connecting a GPU, it's a wattage issue - move the GPU to a different circuit. In general, HDDs shouldn't be on the same circuit as high wattage peripherals, unless there's 100% certainty enough wattage will be available at max load.

Comment: @JW0914 My PSU supply 550W while my PC use about 200W (one GPU) and 325W (two GPUs), so it shouldn't be the problem. Also there was no problem in the past year on this setup.

Comment: @maciek97x You're misunderstanding PSU power circuits - your PSU has multiple power circuits _(refer to its manual)_, with each having a voltage and max amperage rating _(Ohm's Law: V[oltage] x A[mperage] = W[attage] | `V*A = W`)_.  Your GPU or HDDs need to be moved to a different circuit, which you'll verify when you check your manual and verify the circuit powering the GPU.

Comment: They are connected to different circuits. GPU uses 6pin output (max 216W) and drives uses another PSU output.

Comment: @maciek97x Your issue is wattage related [Occam's Razor], as you're experiencing what occurs when an HDD does not have the wattage required to power it. Visually verify all circuits with your PSU's manual, as there's a power issue either with the circuit the HDD(s) are on.

Comment: @JW0914 Then why problem was still reproductible when only nvme sdd was connected? (as I said before)

Comment: @maciek97x Please do your due diligence - per the first paragraph in your question, your issue is wattage related, which you'll discover when you reference your PSU's manual and visually inspect your PSU's branch circuits _(just an FYI, just the two GPUs and CPU require ~440W at load, leaving only 110W (~9A @ 12v) for everything else, which is not going to be all on one circuit)_